# How to signal between process/containers in cpp in efficient way?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, real-time, real-time-clock

### Background:

We have a `clock` process which needs to `signal` other **non child** processes[cpp code] on each clock tick. Each of the process lives in its on `container` (`containerd`).

Besides doing `brute force` of scanning a shared memory on a change(which is very bad in terms of computing resource). Any other effective ways for a `near real-time system` to send a signal for other processes?

### Desired behavior:

1. Make all process to sleep for a time x or until they received a `tick` single from the main `clock`
2. The latency of each process should be small, less than a milisecond.

### Questions:

Is it possible to `wait_event_interruptible_timeout` in the `userspace`. Will it help for the scenario above? Any other solution ?

Comment: what about `select` and the successors? I expect your complete design is event driven... if not, you should split event driven from looping parts.

Comment: Unix domain socket?

Comment: The biggest problem here is that if ten C++ developers get asked what is "best practice for <X>", there will be at least eleven different answers in response. There are very few "best practices" in C++ which are founded in facts and citations; everything else is mostly opinion.

Comment: SO usage note: Avoid using syntax highlighting for non-code. In this case clock is generic, but `clock` has [a specific meaning](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html). signal would mean "Send some sort of message. I haven't decided on what yet" while `signal` means "I know [exactly what means of communication](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) I wish to use." This leads to unnecessary ambiguity in the question.

Comment: @Klaus `select` and `pselect` can be an option. Is it possible to do `single writer` - `multireader` with `pselect`?